# How to convert .csv to .xls

Tags: export-to-excel, xls, import-from-csv, gnumeric, ssconvert

I have a simple .csv file.

Is it possible to convert it to .xls using the command line tool `ssconvert`?

I would also need to specify the name of the sheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ln -s input.csv MySheetName
ssconvert MySheetName output.xls
```

The OP asked how to convert csv to xls while controlling the sheet name in the output.

The generated .xls file will use the name of the input CSV file as the sheet name, so you can symlink the .csv to anything you want (or rename the input file) to produce the desired result.

The previous answer implies that --list-exporters leads to a solution, but it merely lists exporter names with no information about their options, and no options are documented in the man page for xls-exporters.  Experimentally, none of the exporters which can create .xls accept options (they fail with "The file saver does not take options" if you use -O).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You must specify names with extensions as input and output files.

For example:

```
 ssconvert in.csv out.xls
```

Using **--list-importers** and **--list-exporters** options can take a look to available formats.